# Facebook Graph API: Access all public posts through a user's session?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a valid access token for a user (hashed with my app's secret to generate `appsecret_proof`). I'm trying to access all of that user's **public** posts (status updates, photos, links, etc.) with a single call to `/{user-id}/feed` (or `/{user-id}/posts` or something else). Unfortunately, the calls are returning empty `data` structures in the response.

I've been able to piece together most of what I'm looking for by retrieving `/{user-id}/statuses`, `/{user-id}/links`, `/{user-id}/photos`, etc. and reassembling the responses into a single set of results, but that seems a little hamfisted. I don't think I'm missing any permissions because the more specific calls are working fine, and I'm not after non-public posts as that would require `read_stream`. The only other thing I can think of is that my app is still a test app and maybe it will work differently after it's approved?

Any tips on accessing users' public posts? I'm using the latest version of the PHP SDK if that makes a difference. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Opened a [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1541482859459238/) with Facebook per Tobi's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the docs, it's quite clear there:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed/#readperms

**Permissions**

> - Any valid access token is required to view public links.
> - A user access token with read_stream permission is required.
> - Only posts whose authors have also granted read_stream permission to the app will be shown.

So you'll only be able to retrive public links with any kind of Access Token, for all others you'll need `read_stream`, which is close to impossible to get granted during app review.

Comment: That's not very helpful. It should be clear from my question that I've read the documentation in detail. We can focus on this particular item, though. Can you explain why `/{user-id}/links` returns data but `/{user-id}/feed?filter=app_2309869772` returns nothing?

Comment: Well, then you should have understood that it's not possible to receive status updates, photos etc. because calling `/{user_id}/feed` requires `read_stream` permissions of this user. Baseline: You cannot get even public posts without `read_stream`. That's what the docs say. Public links is an exception and explicitly stated in the docs as well. And, in your question, there was nothing about filtering the feed. You can file a bug report anytime and see what FB says

Comment: Ignore status updates and photos for the time being. Why isn't /feed returning public links (with or without the filter)? Is my syntax invalid?

Comment: Open a bug with FB and let them check.

Comment: My bug report initially gained some attention, but was ultimately closed with a "by design" status, as you thought from the get-go. I've also learned that you can't get at-mentions on status updates, and that ETags are recomputed on every call whether or not the underlying data has changed, leading me to question why Facebook has even bothered to develop such a half-baked API in the first place. Oh, well. Thanks for your help!